# Is it acceptable to say "I am off" in meaning that I'm tired or something like that?

Tags: idioms

Is it acceptable in English to say **"I am off"** in meaning that I'm tired or something like that? I heard it from non native English speaker, that's why I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Maybe "I am feeling off" but not just "I am off".  [You can see examples here.](https://www.google.com/search?q=feeling+off+today)

Answer (score 8):

Not quite.

> Well, **I'm off**!

Means that you're **leaving**. See: [TheFreeDictionary - I'm off](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/I'm+off).

> This song sounds/feels a little **off**.

Means that there is something not quite right about this song to you. It feels weird. A thread on ELU about that: [What does the idiom “to sound a little off” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84659/what-does-the-idiom-to-sound-a-little-off-mean)

If you wanna say you're not feeling well, you could say:

> I'm feeling a bit **under the weather**, I think I'm going to go home.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible you may be thinking of

> I'm *a bit* off *(BrE)*
>   *I am feeling unwell*

and therefore the speaker is feeling tired as a result.

To only express tired might be

> I'm tired *(obviously)*
>   I'm knackered *(BrE)*

Usually expressing tiredness and sickness are kept separate.

As pointed out, simply using "I'm off" would usually mean

> I'm off *(to some destination)*
>   *I'm leaving/going*

Answer (score 3):

Off means many things, including not being normal, being sub-standard, or separated from a place or thing. It does not mean "tired," and if you were to state this, a native speaker would understand it to mean that you're feeling unusual or are ill.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think so. It may be a little unusual, but I think it would be understood easily by a high percentage of native speakers.

The more "usual" statement would be "I feel [a little] off" or "I'm a little off" or "I'm off my game", etc. but I think "I am off" or "I'm off" are adequate and perfectly understandable.

Comment: I don't know that I would assume that "I'm off" meant the same as "I feel off". I would probably assume it was a variation of "I'm out - see ya" or "I'm off work - see ya". It would be highly context dependent.

Comment: Context is important. Since almost no utterances are made outside of a context, I think it would be understandable in the large majority of situations. 
If there was no indication that someone was  going anywhere...and/or the idea that someone wasn't perhaps up to their usual standards, I can easiyl see "I'm off" (meaning "I'm off [today|right now|lately]") being perfectly acceptable and understandable. 
Are you a native American English speaker, @ColleenV?

Comment: If you can't tell, does it matter? I would think the region I'm from would be more relevant than whether English is my first or fourth language.

Comment: To me, it matters not. ;)